# MySQL Stored Procedure Case Statement Syntax Error - Contd 2

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

One Syntax Error in the following code. 
The response of the mysql was

> Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near ''300ml','500ml','1lit','2lit')
>   VALUES(m_cust_id,IN_book_id,(SELECT Rate.Can*Book' at line 24 SQL
>   Statement

The following is the procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `calculate_amount` (in IN_book_id INT,  in IN_qty INT )
BEGIN
-- declare
DECLARE m_prdct VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE m_cust_id INT(5);

-- select into
SELECT 
    Product
FROM
    Bookings
WHERE
    Book_id = IN_book_id INTO m_prdct;

SELECT 
    Cust_id
FROM
    Bookings
WHERE
    Book_id = IN_book_id INTO m_cust_id;

-- conditionals & action
IF (m_prdct = '20ltr') THEN
INSERT INTO Amount (Cust_id,Book_id,Can,'300ml','500ml','1lit','2lit') VALUES(m_cust_id,IN_book_id,(SELECT Rate.Can*Bookings.Qty FROM Rate,Bookings WHERE Bookings.Book_id=IN_book_id),0,0,0,0); 

ELSEIF (m_prdct = '300ml') THEN
INSERT INTO Amount(Cust_id,Book_id,Can,'300ml','500ml','1lit','2lit') VALUES(m_cust_id,IN_book_id,0,(SELECT Rate.300ml*Bookings.Qty FROM Rate,Bookings WHERE Bookings.Book_id=IN_book_id),0,0,0);

ELSEIF (m_prdct = '500ml') THEN 
INSERT INTO Amount(Cust_id,Book_id,Can,'300ml','500ml','1lit','2lit') VALUES(m_cust_id,IN_book_id,0,0,(SELECT Rate.500ml*Bookings.Qty FROM Rate,Bookings WHERE Bookings.Book_id=IN_book_id),0,0); 

ELSEIF (m_prdct = '1ltr') THEN 
INSERT INTO Amount(Cust_id,Book_id,Can,'300ml','500ml','1lit','2lit') VALUES(m_cust_id,IN_book_id,0,0,0,(SELECT Rate.1lit*Bookings.Qty FROM Rate,Bookings WHERE Bookings.Book_id=IN_book_id),0); 

ELSE 
    INSERT INTO Amount(Cust_id,Book_id,Can,'300ml','500ml','1lit','2lit') VALUES(m_cust_id,IN_book_id,0,0,0,0,(SELECT Rate.2lit*Bookings.Qty FROM Rate,Bookings WHERE Bookings.Book_id=IN_book_id)); 
-- end
END IF;
END
```

Comment: You should use `column names` instead of `literals` inside `INSERT INTO Amount( ... ,'300ml','500ml','1lit','2lit'`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Those are the column names my friend.

Comment: I think they must be double-quoted, such as `"300ml"`, then.

Comment: Oh, thank you but it didn't work. @BarbarosÖzhan

Comment: :)  You're welcome.. What else error did you get now ?

Comment: Same error. @BarbarosÖzhan

Comment: You need to use backtick `\``, not `'` or `"`

Answer (score 0):

[image: The mySql showing "8 errors found" at the bottom]

[image: The parsing error thrown]

The script applied successfully even if it showed error. The Back Tick to column names starting with digits solved the issue. Upon Refreshing, it got changed from _SYNTAX_ERROR to its actual name.